# how to embed javadb or hsqldb into java application with hibernate using netbeans?

Tags: java, hibernate, netbeans, hsqldb, javadb

I successfuly embedded javadb in my application using the classpath ,but here's the problem : I want hibernate to be able to work with the database,but I always get an error in netbeans sayng "enable to establish connection ".
AnyHelp please ?

Comment: No offense, but your question is very wiered worded. However: obviously your application does not know where the data base is. You need to give an IP adress, usually an URL, a user, a password, and perhaps a port and worst case a JDBC driver. For that you usually have a properties file where this parts are defined in.

Comment: Thanks ,but what I was trying to say is that I want to use a local database (to be stored in a file inside the application ) ,and I read that I can only do that using javadb or hsqldb,but the problem is that hibernate is not working with the locale database

Comment: Then you have to figure how this "javadb" or "hsqldb" is supposed to work with hibernate. The url part of the "connection parameters" will contain "localhost" or "127.0.0.1" as IP adress then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The URL for a local HSQLDB database is `jdbc:hsqldb:file:file_path_name` The file_path_name is usually an absolute path with a name at the end. The database engine will then create a few files with the given name, but predefined extensions. An example of this is: `jdbc:hsqldb:file:/mydata/mydb` which will produce `mydb.properties` , `mydb.script` and a couple other files in the `/mydata` directory.